# Add two string columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am trying to add two columns together of char data type in order to combine their code with description.

table1 has all of the data I need and I am only referencing table2 in order to get the description.

For example, table1 has column:

```
Code

1
2
```

and table 2 has columns:

```
Code      Description

1         Football
2         Soccer
```

I'm basically trying to write a query where I can have one column show

```
1 - Football
2 - Soccer
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    a.Code + ' - ' + b.Description
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.Code = b.Code
```

and while this does add the columns together, it also generates a lot of duplicate rows for some reason, I am assuming because of the LEFT JOIN.

Basically I am just wanting that whatever code is in table1, to match that code in table2 and to bring over that Description.

Comment: You stated in the comments that you are using 2008. Time to upgrade mate. There is less than a month left until this product is no longer supported at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Left Join you get the values in Table A that may not exist in Table B.  To eliminate the duplicates you could try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Code + ' - ' + b.Description
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.Code = b.Code
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    a.Code + ' - ' + b.Description
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.Code = b.Code
GROUP BY a.Code, b.Description
```

Comment: I was able to figure out why it was returning so many rows. I did not realize that the Code also was linked to other values as well, so I had to add another filter in my WHERE clause to exclude those values. I used the second portion that you suggested along with my edited WHERE clause to exclude the extra rows.

Answer (score 1):

use coalesce in case of null for 2nd table and use `distinct` incase of avoid duplicate

```
SELECT distinct a.Code +' - ' + coalesce(b.Description,'')
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.Code = b.Code

or try like below and i dont think you needed join you can do it just by using 2nd tabale
SELECT 
    b.Code ||' - ' || b.Description)
from
table2 b
```

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2008 so I believe CONCAT is not supported yet when I try it as it says it is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ISNULL` to handle missing value from table2:

```
SELECT 
    a.Code + ISNULL(' - ' + b.Description, '')
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.Code = b.Code
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the relationship between table1 and table2? The only way I see the above query returning duplicates is: If relationship between table1 and table2 is 1:Many. Meaning one row in table1 can match to multiple rows in table2.

1. Do you need to fetch a code that exists in table1 even if it does not have a corresponding description in table2? If so, use a LEFT JOIN like below.

   - If table2 has direct duplicates, then using a DISTINCT will remove
     duplicates in the final result:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT
          a.Code + ' - ' + COALESCE(b.Description, '')
   FROM table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
          ON a.Code = b.Code;
   ```

   - If one code has multiple different descriptions in table2, then your
     final resultset is expected to have multiple rows for the same code 
     but with different description by running the above query because of
     the nature of data in the tables.
2. Do you need to fetch a code that exists in table1 only if it has a corresponding description in table2? If so, use a INNER JOIN like below.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT
          a.Code + ' - ' + b.Description
   FROM table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
          ON a.Code = b.Code;
   ```